# Export list versioning history into Excel

Tags: excel, export, history, last-modified

I need to track field changes/last modified within a list.  From my research I have had a few potential leads but it ends up in programming which I am complete noob at, or, creating a workflow within SPD which I am more comfortable doing.  I figured the fastest way to track it is to export the entire list versioning history into Excel so I can manipulate the data from there for analysis.

Is exporting this the best way to track field changes, or creating a workflow?  If so is there an workflow example I can work off?

Thank you,
Claude
-Rookie SharePoint End User

Comment: Hi pnuts, exporting using the Excel export function within the list.  An example would be the AnalysisStatus field was set to "Initiated" on 7/1/14.  Today someone changed it to "Ready".  I want to have a way to track the date that particular field was modified.  There are about 10 fields I would like to track and then export it using the export function within the list.

Comment: It's a custom list that has a InfoPath form.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a calculated column for each of the fields that I want to track a modified date for.  Then within those calc columns would reference the field.  Create a workflow that states if CalcAnalysisStatus <> AnalysisStatus, input modified date in ModDateAnalysisStatus.  Is that a good way to track it?  It sounds easy but I have never done a workflow but I will Google it to death! haha